# Rails syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

Where is the error in this I can't see it:

```
news = News.find(:all, :conditions => [":simulation_id => session[:sim_id] AND :created_at > session[:last_login]"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
news = News.find(:all, :conditions => ["simulation_id = ? AND created_at > ?", session[:sim_id], session[:last_login]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions string won't be evaluated as you expect:

```
[":simulation_id => session[:sim_id] AND :created_at > session[:last_login]"]
```

change that to

```
["simulation_id = ? AND created_at > ?", session[:sim_id], session[:last_login]]
```

Comment: simulation_id should be '=', not '=>'

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `Model.all` instead of `Model.find(:all)` which would look something like this:

```
news = News.all(:conditions => ["simulation_id = ? AND created_at > ?", session[:sim_id], session[:last_login]])
```